# How to format date in QlikView

Tags: uppercase, date-formatting, qlikview

I have a table with invoices and made a calendar table with all the dates for the invoices, it looks like this:

```
InvoiceCalendar:
LOAD Distinct
        InvoiceDate,
        Year(InvoiceDate) as InvoiceYear,
        Month(InvoiceDate) as InvoiceMonth, 
        Day(InvoiceDate) as InvoiceDay,
        Date(MonthStart(InvoiceDate), 'YYYY-MM') as InvoiceYearMonth
Resident
    Invoice;
```

It works fine. The InvoiceMonth field is all in lower case like jan, feb, apr. I would like to have them in upper case. I've tried with Upper(Month(InvoiceDate)... they all got upper case but in some weird random order.

Then I tried to use Date to format like `Date(InvoiceDate, 'MMM') as InvoiceMonth` but I can't get it working. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very top of the Main tab in your script you should see this default line

```
SET MonthNames='Jan;Feb;Mar;Apr;May;Jun;Jul;Aug;Sep;Oct;Nov;Dec';
```

Type in this list with upper case values. Should solve your problem. You shouldn't need the upper then either